getting 401 error while running jenkins pipeline in docker image creation step
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\jenkins-declarative-ci-cd-demo>docker build -t xyz/spring-cicda:3.0 . 
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 174B 0.1s done
#1 DONE 0.1s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17
#2 ...

#3 [auth] library/openjdk:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
#3 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17
#2 ERROR: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fopenjdk%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM openjdk:17
   2 |     WORKDIR /appContainer
   3 |     COPY ./target/jenkinsCiCd.jar /appContainer
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: openjdk:17: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fopenjdk%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized

i tried to add "buildkit": false in the settings in the spring docker enging section but after that my docker desktop is not opening.
